Correlation of Group of Questions in Likert Scale answers
let's say that we have a response survey data frame with 6 columns.Each column is a question.Q1,Q2,Q3,...,Q6. The responses are from 1 to 5. 1 is translated to Very Bad,4 to Bad,3 to neutral,2 to good, 1 to Very Good. Also consider that A is a group of questions of q1,q2,q3, B is alone the question q4, C has q5 and q6. My finally task is to find the correlation between all groups.A with B, B with C A with C and so on as the correlation matrix shows. My question is : That the responses are levels of a factor.Ranks.Each response is a rank.It might be numeric but it is a rank. If I take the the mean of the questions can then use the Spearman Correlation Coefficient? Or I have to take the median? If instead of Spearman (that deals with ranks) can I use Pearson coefficient?

likert_levels <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
set.seed(42)
library(dplyr)
df <-
  tibble(
    "q1" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "q2" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "q3" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "q4" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "q5" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "q6" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))


df2 = tibble(categories = c("A","A","A","B","C","C"),
             questions = c("q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6"))

df2
df%>%
  mutate(id = row_number())%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!id,names_to = "questions",values_to = "responses")%>%
  left_join(.,df2,by="questions")
  


df_cor=df%>%
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.double)%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(QA = mean(c(q1, q2, q3)),
         QB = mean(c(q4)),
         QC = mean(c(q5, q6)))%>%
  select(QA,QB,QC)

cor(df_cor, method = "spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
cor(df_cor, method = "pearson",  use="pairwise.complete.obs")

